# Getting com.android.volley.ServerError when uploading images with larger size

Tags: android, android-volley

Thanks in advance. I'm using Android volley library to upload image to server in Base64 String format. For small images having size less than 500 kilobyte is fine.
But for larges size images having size more than 500 kb.
My code is for getting image from gallery -

```
Cursor cursor =   
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(imageUri, 
                filePath, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String imagePath = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
                cursor.close();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                Bitmap bitmap;
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(options.outHeight/(float)300);
                int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(options.outWidth/(float)300);
                if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1){
                    if ( heightRatio > widthRatio){
                        options.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
                    } else {
                        options.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
                    }
                }
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;


                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

                int numBytesByCount = bitmap.getByteCount();
```

and put string as map to the function given below

```
public void volleyPostRequest(Activity activity,  String taleUrl, String message, GenerateResponse generateResponse, final Map<String, String> params){
        final ProgressDialog progress  = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progress.setMessage("Loading");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();
        if (isOnline()){
            CommonUtility.customShowToast(mContext, "Please check your network connection");
            progress.dismiss();
            return;
        }
        this.mGenerateResponse = generateResponse;
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        String url = CommonUtility.BASE_URL+taleUrl;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                        NetworkConnection.this.mGenerateResponse.success(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                CommonUtility.customShowToast( mContext, "Can't reach server" );
                NetworkConnection.this.mGenerateResponse.errorOnConnection(error.toString());
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams(){
                return  params;
            }

        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
            @Override
            public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                return 100000;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                return 50000;
            }

            @Override
            public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Comment: if you are geting server eroor then its not volley fault plz check your api or server side may b they have any restruction for large file......

Comment: another option is add Retery Policy to increase request time

Comment: u wlcm.........